# Get index of ListBoxItem - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

How do I get the index of a `ListBoxItem`?

The `ListBox` has binding to a collection of XML nodes through `XmlDataProvider`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar question which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451422/wpf-bind-to-item-index-from-within-itemtemplate-of-itemscontrol/3451690#3451690)

Basically you set the ListBox's `AlternationCount` to something really high, and bind to the `AlternationIndex` on each item

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="100">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
                                      Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @Greg: Agreed, but it's the only way I've found to do it so far with a ListBox. I'm hoping they add a property in some future version of WPF

Comment: @punker76 I think ListBoxes are Virtualized by default, so that shouldn't be the case

Comment: @Rachel ok, virtualisation is the default, but the alternation index doesn't works. i created a little project, try scrolling down and up and you will see http://jkarger.de/WpfStackOverflowSpielWiese.exe (.net 4)

Answer (score 12):

You can get the index of the `ListBoxItem` from the `ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(listBoxItem);
```

Comment: This works better than the accepted answer when using ItemsSource while having identical references

Answer (score -4):

The property `SelectedIndex` would work. It all depends on how you're doing your binding

You probably want to bind the `SelectedIndex` dependency property to some property of the object connected to it's datacontext e.g.

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding MySelectedIndex}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"/>
```

but you could obviously do this

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding MySelectedIndex}">
  <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```