# WPF MultiColumn ListBox showing index

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

i have a multicolumn `ListBox` as you can see below.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstQuestions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="544" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Margin="0,0,0,-0.5" SelectionChanged="lstQuestions_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding qID}"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding imgPath}" Width="140" Height="50" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I want to show the index number (like 1, 2, 3 ...) instead of `<TextBlock Text="{Binding qID}"/>` in first column, how can I do that?

Edit: Binding code behind

```
 public class QList
{
    public string qID { get; set; }
    public string imgPath { get; set; }
    public int ansCount { get; set; }
    public string rightAns { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public static List<QList> questions = new List<QList>();
```

last one

```
lstQuestions.ItemsSource = Test.questions;
```

The first two are in a class called `Test`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the index of a listboxitem in a WPF listbox instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716073/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-a-listboxitem-in-a-wpf-listbox-instance)

Comment: Text in all items become zero now.

Comment: BTW I don´t see any binding to `ListBox` `ItemSource`...

Comment: There you go i added it

Comment: what's your question? Binding is not working? or you want a sequence number to see

Comment: I want to display index number of item in the left column

Comment: do you mean `qID`?

Comment: No the `ListBox` index