# Access current ItemsControl index via binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, stackpanel

I have the following piece of code

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Offers}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <wpf:Card Padding="32" Margin="5" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData }">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,-30" Height="107">
                                <TextBlock
                                    Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}">
                                    <Run Text="Offer " />

                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarDescription}" />
                                <Separator Height="1" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <Button Content="Select" 
                                        Width="72" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                        Command="{Binding SelectOfferCommand}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        </wpf:Card>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

This produces a bunch of repeated boxes, every has a button. Every time i click the button i want to access current box index (from ItemsControl's ItemsSource) and pass it as a command parameter. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Why? You can pass the actual item that the itemTemplate is bound to.

Comment: Don't naming visual object as it's type. You should change the name of your ItemsControl to another name eg: "ItemsControlOffers".

Comment: @UçanKartal For what reason? "ItemsControl" is a perfectly valid name here.

Comment: @Clemens Because when you have a lot of windows, it will help you to distinct between the entities.

Comment: @UçanKartal That doesn't make sense. There is certainly only one window here.

Comment: Ok, i figured it out                                                                                                           `Command= "{Binding ElementName=ItemsControlOffers,  Path=DataContext.OnSelectOfferCommand}"                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Index}"`                                                                                                     I added an Index property to each Offer and passed it as command parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the current `Index` of an `ItemsControl` using the `AlterationIndex`.

[See more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Example:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Offers}"
              AlternationCount="1000">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <wpf:Card Padding="32" Margin="5" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData }">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,-30" Height="107">
                    <TextBlock
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}">
                        <Run Text="Offer " />

                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CarDescription}" />
                    <Separator Height="1" Visibility="Hidden" />
                <Button Content="Select" 
                        Width="72" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                        Command="{Binding SelectOfferCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </wpf:Card>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Don't do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511180/wpf-itemscontrol-the-current-listitem-index-in-the-itemssource/17962582#17962582.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be suitable for you to add `index` property to each `Offer` while creating `Offers` and send this index OnSelectOfferCommand. It will be much easier

ps I think i must explain my answer: My sugestion is not only easier in realisation, but also it is a good practice to seperate busines logic from UI. In this case if UI will be changed, changes will not effect whole ordering process