# Bind dynamic value coming from GUI to the viewmodel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

There is an itemscontrol in one of my views that lets the user reorder the items by an up/down button.

My question is on how I can flow the current index of the items to my viewmodel

The following questions address on how to find the current index (not so clean but it does the job)

[WPF - Bind to Item Index from within ItemTemplate of ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451422/wpf-bind-to-item-index-from-within-itemtemplate-of-itemscontrol)

Now, how can I modify the XAML so that it binds this index to a property on my viewmodel?

**edit** The question is about how to do it in XAML declaratively. A possible solution is to do it in code using and ObservableCollection and subscribe to CollectionChanged

Kind Regards, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your items store an index poperty that you need to update when they are re-ordered in the UI?

I would create a view model that exposes my items as an `ObservableCollection`. You can then handle the `CollectionChanged` event which will fire when the items are re-ordered in your view model. At this point you can enumerate the collection of items updating their indices.

Comment: Hello ColinE. Good answer and I have went that rout after I could found a way to do it in the XML through databinding. 
The question is about how to do it in XAML declaratively.