# Accessing controls in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am creating a WPF application. I want a page to be displayed on each button click.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DashBoardApps}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Abc">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Controls:FishEyeControl />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button MouseDown="Button_MouseDown">
                            <Image  Source="{Binding Path=ApplicationImage}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtAppName" Text="{Binding Path=ApplicationName}" TextAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="7px" Foreground="#eff7ff" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="txtAppName" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

There are 6 buttons in total.On the button click I want a page to be displayed.(different pages for different buttons).
In the code behind I've done something like this

```
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as ItemsControl;
        if (s == Abc.Items.GetItemAt(1))//if it is the first button. Not sure if it is right
        {
           //Code to display page
        }

    }
```

I want to know which button generated the event. As in, if the first button was clicked then page1 has to be displayed. So I tried using `GetItemAt()` function to see if the first button was clicked(to display the first page). However it doesn't work and I am not sure if this approach is correct.

P.S Simply stated I want to know which button generated the event-Can this be done using index. If so, how?
Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual Button is passed to the event handler in the sender argument:

```
Button button = sender as Button;
```

There is however a problem. Since Button handles the MouseDown event, you won't get it. You would have to either add a handler for the [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown) event, or better for the Button's [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) event.

And just as a note: The [ItemCollection.GetItemAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.getitemat.aspx) method uses a zero-based index.

EDIT: Here is how to bind the Button's `Tag` property to the ItemsControl's `AlternationIndex` property and how to utilize that index in the Button's Click handler:

```
<ItemsControl ... AlternationCount="2147483647">
...
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="Button_Click"
                    Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
                                  Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}">
            ...
        </StackPanel>
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

With the XAML namespace `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` you could alternatively write

```
<ItemsControl AlternationCount="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}">
```

The Click handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    int index = (int)button.Tag;
    // get page by zero-based index
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes. I know the actual button is passed as sender. Now I want to know if Button1 was clicked or Button2 was clicked.Kindly note Here I'm using ItemsControl. Is it possible to do it using Index?

Comment: How do I find if it was the first button or some other button?

Comment: Sure, but you didn't ask that. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3451422/1136211) for a possible solution. You might bind for example the Button's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag) property to the AlternationIndex and then access the index in Tag from your Click handler.

Comment: Could you possibly show how to do that? I added the `AlternationIndex` to the button's Tag. How do I access the index in the CLick handler? Sorry as I'm new to this.