# Why AlternationIndex returns 0 for all items in ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I search for some way to show the items index in a `ItemsControl` that is using `DataTemplate`. So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451422/wpf-bind-to-item-index-from-within-itemtemplate-of-itemscontrol) good question. I used the idea in that question but all the values are zero! The only different between my code and the code in that question is that my controls (that is going to show the index) is not directly in the `DataTemplate`. It is in a `Grid` and the `Grid` is in the `DataTemplate`

**Here is my code:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                // column definitions
                <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                       Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
                       Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"/>
                // some other controls
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Result:**

```
0
0
0
// and so on
```

**What I expect to be shown:**

```
0
1
2
// and so on
```

What is wrong whit this code?

Comment: Did you do that: `Set AlternationCount on your ItemsControl to something greater than the max possible count of your items` (from the linked questions accepted answer)?

Comment: Your code sais something different.^^ Just add `AlternationCount="1000"` so your ItemsControl and it should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `AlternationCount` property of your property needs to be set.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" AlternationCount={Binding CountOfItems}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            // column definitions
            <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                   Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
                   Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
                   />
            // some other controls
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: In the example above, if you'd like the `AlternationIndex` to be either `0` or `1`, set the `AlternationCount` to `2`.

Comment: @Chrisjan Lodewyks I can't have it working with a combobox. I use these properties for ComboBox: ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectName.ListName}" AlternationCount="{Binding ObjectName.ListName.Count}" . Any idea?